# Speed up the evaluation of For loop

Tags: parallelization, for

I am writing a script to simulate the spins. I have used "For" loop, but the execution takes long time as I have a lot of dataset.
Has there any way to make it faster ?
Here is the code:

```
Ix = 1/2 {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}; Iy = 1/2 {{0, -I}, {I, 0}}; Iz = 
 1/2 {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}; Io = IdentityMatrix[2];
I1z = KroneckerProduct[Iz, Io];
I2z = KroneckerProduct[Io, Iz];
I1x = KroneckerProduct[Ix, Io];
I2x = KroneckerProduct[Io, Ix];
I1y = KroneckerProduct[Iy, Io];
I2y = KroneckerProduct[Io, Iy];
 \[Rho]1={{1/2, 0, I/2, 0}, {0, -(1/2), 0, I/2}, {-(I/2), 0, 1/2, 
     0}, {0, -(I/2), 0, -(1/2)}}

  \[Omega]D = 2 \[Pi] 20; 
  \[Omega]CS = 2 \[Pi] 5 ; 
  \[Omega]r = 2 \[Pi] 15;
  \[Gamma] = \[Beta] = \[Pi]/4;

 aq = 100(*ms*); DwL = 0.002(*Dwell time in ms*);
 time = Table[i, {i, 0, aq, DwL}];
 
 U0t = ConstantArray[0, {Length@time - 1, 2, 2}]; \[Rho]t = 
  ConstantArray[0, {Length@time, 2, 2}];
 Mxt = Myt = ConstantArray[0, Length@time - 1];
    
  H0 = \[Omega]D (\[Sqrt]2 Sin[
         2 \[Beta]] Cos[\[Omega]r t + \[Gamma]] - (Sin[\[Beta]])^2 Cos[
         2 \[Omega]r t + 2 \[Gamma]]) (2 I1z.I2z - I1x.I2x - I1y.I2y) +
         \[Omega]CS (-\[Sqrt]2 Sin[
         2 \[Beta]] Cos[\[Omega]r t + \[Gamma]] + (Sin[\[Beta]])^2 Cos[
         2 \[Omega]r t + 2 \[Gamma]]) (I1z + I2z);  

   integrals = Table[Integrate[H0, {t, time[[i]], time[[i + 1]]}],{i, 1, Length@time - 1}];
   
    For[i = 1, i < Length@time, i++, dt = time[[i + 1]] - time[[i]];
        U0t[[i]] = MatrixExp[-I integrals[[i]]];
        \[Rho]t[[i]] = U0t[[i]].\[Rho]1.U0t[[i]]\[ConjugateTranspose];
         Mxt[[i]] = Tr[\[Rho]t[[i]].I1x];
         Myt[[i]] = Tr[\[Rho]t[[i]].I1y];
    ]
```

Any suggestion will be really helpful!

Comment: Start here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12 Do not use a `For` loop. Once it's rewritten in more structured form, it'll almost certainly be faster, easier to parallelize, and much easier to see where speed could be improved.

Comment: Also, avoid unnecessary symbolic computation. Do you really need these integrals symbolically? I didn't wait for them to finish computing. I expect the result is huge, unproductive to use, and takes ages to evaluate numerically.

Comment: yes, I need the integration, there is no way to avoid.. I tried to integrate first before use it in the loop. but that does not improve much.

Comment: @Szabolcs `Integrate` uses the numeric branch here, because the interval endpoints are machine precision numbers. The problem is just that this are so _many_ integrals. So the key here is actually to do the integral symbolically _once_. ;)

Comment: @PPyne What is `\[Rho]1`? It is undefined so far.

Comment: \[Rho]1={{1/2, 0, I/2, 0}, {0, -(1/2), 0, I/2}, {-(I/2), 0, 1/2, 
  0}, {0, -(I/2), 0, -(1/2)}}.

Answer (score 5):

It takes already extremely long to compute `integral`. Note that your integrands are basically a functions times a constant $4 \times 4$ matrix. So just integrating the function and then multiplying by the matrix should help already. We can accelerate this further by employing the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: We use `Integrate` to compute anti-derivatives symbolically and then compute differences of their function values to get the integrals. Finally we use `TensorProduct` to multiply the scala integrals with the matrix:

```
F[t_] = ComplexExpand[ Re[Integrate[\[Omega]D (\[Sqrt]2 Sin[2 \[Beta]] Cos[\[Omega]r t + \[Gamma]] - (Sin[\[Beta]])^2 Cos[2 \[Omega]r t + 2 \[Gamma]]), t]]];
G[t_] = ComplexExpand[ Re[Integrate[\[Omega]CS (-\[Sqrt]2 Sin[2 \[Beta]] Cos[\[Omega]r t + \[Gamma]] + (Sin[\[Beta]])^2 Cos[2 \[Omega]r t + 2 \[Gamma]]), t]]];
\[CapitalDelta]F = Differences[F[time]];
\[CapitalDelta]G = Differences[G[time]];
integrals =  TensorProduct[\[CapitalDelta]F, (2 I1z . I2z - I1x . I2x - I1y . I2y)] + TensorProduct[\[CapitalDelta]G, (I1z + I2z)];
```

All entries of `integrals` compute in a fraction of a second.

And here some further performance improvements. *Mathematica* is an interpreted language, and those do typically not well with for loops.  While you code would be nearly optimimal in *C* or *C++*, there are better ways to achive your goals in *Mathematica*. For example, you do not need to preallocate arrays for your results if you can use command `Map` (`/@`). Btw., `Map` is one of the reasons why I adopted *Mathematica* in the first place; it is so much easier to understand, less error prone and often faster at runtime than `Do`, `For`, or `Table`.

Next thing we can use is to let `Dot` operation thread over the list of `U0t`. Here we can use `Compile` with the option `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}`.

Finally, `Tr[A.B]` is *always* a bad idea, because `A.B` is an $O(n^3)$ operation while `Dot[Flatten[A].Flatten[B]]` does the same and only requires $O(n^2)$ time. By clever reshaping of `\[Rho]t` with `Flatten`, we can even compute all `Dot`s with a single call to a matrix-vector `Dot`. The backend BLAS library is highly optimized and performs the task 35 times faster on my machine. (And I think the `Flatten` is actually for free here.)

```
\[Rho]1 = {{1/2, 0, I/2, 0}, {0, -(1/2), 0, I/2}, {-(I/2), 0, 1/2, 0}, {0, -(I/2), 0, -(1/2)}};

cf = With[{\[Rho]1 = \[Rho]1},
   Compile[{{U, _Complex, 2}}, U . \[Rho]1 . U\[ConjugateTranspose], 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
   ];


U0t = MatrixExp /@ (-I integrals);
\[Rho]t = cf[U0t];

With[{\[Rho] = Flatten[\[Rho]t, {{1}, {2, 3}}]},
  Mxt = \[Rho] . Flatten[I1x];
  Myt = \[Rho] . Flatten[I1y];
  ];
```

Comment: This tensor product thing reduces the time significantly (the whole script runs within 5seconds and before it took 5hours). many thanks

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: In the script I actually have to vary the \[Beta] and \[Gamma] values as well. The code works fine even when I vary the values but a bit slower again to perform all the integration. Has there a way to get rid of it? Here is the code:
\[Beta] = \[Gamma] = Table[i, {i, \[Pi]/36, 179  \[Pi]/180, \[Pi]/36}];
\[Omega]Dt = \[Omega]D (\[Sqrt]2 Sin[
       2 \[Beta]] Cos[\[Omega]r t + \[Gamma]] - (Sin[\[Beta]])^2 Cos[
       2 \[Omega]r t + 2 \[Gamma]]) ;
Integrate[\[Omega]Dt, t];

Comment: Delete the definition of `\[Beta]` and `\[Gamma]`, and replace `F[t_] = ...` by `F[t_, \[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] = ...` and `G[t_] = ...` by `G[t_, \[Beta]_, \[Gamma]_] = ...` as well. This does the symbolic integration once, for arbitrary values of `\[Beta]` and `\[Gamma]`. Then in the loop over `\[Beta]` and `\[Gamma]` do just `\[CapitalDelta]F  = F[time, \[Beta], \[Gamma]]` and `\[CapitalDelta]G  = G[time, \[Beta], \[Gamma]]` and proceed from there as before.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It helps.

Answer (score 5):

The time consuming step is not the For loop, but the many integrals. Therefore, calculate the indefinite integral first:

```
integ[t_] = Integrate[H0 // FullSimplify, t]
```

[image]

Now you can calculate the table of integrals:

```
integs =  Table[integ[time[[i + 1]]] - integ[time[[i]]], {i, 1,    Length@time - 1}]
```

With this we can get U0t;

```
U0t =  MatrixExp[-I #] & /@ integs;
```

And from this we can get the rest:

```
ρ1 = {{1/2, 0, I/2, 0}, {0, -(1/2), 0, I/2}, {-(I/2), 0, 1/2, 
    0}, {0, -(I/2), 0, -(1/2)}};
ρt = # . ρ1 . #\[ConjugateTranspose] & /@ U0t;
Mxt = Tr[# . I1x] & /@ ρt;
Myt = Tr[# . I1y] & /@ ρt;
```